# How do I remove the last N rows from a csv using R when the total number of rows can change?

Tags: r, csv, row

I have a model that produces an output csv with some irrelevant material at the end:

```
    useful.data
    useful.x useful.y useful.z
    1        1        1
    2        2        2 
    3        3        3
```

useless.data
    useless.x useless.y useless.z
    1         1         1
    2         2         2 
    3         3         3

The issue is the number of rows I want to keep can change depending on the model run. I've never used an if statement in R but I think that looks like my best bet here in that I should use it once I get to the row that says 'useless.data'

Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: `head(df, -N)` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
all_content <- readLines("csvFileHere") 
numToSkip <- *rows to skip here*

read.csv2(text = all_content, nrows = length(f) - numToSkip, header =
FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

With the code above you will be able to change the amount of rows to skip.

Just a little advice. Always make sure if the answer provided is true, so test this answer with your dataset and check it it actually works or not!